# How to put a command to the buttons on JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

So i have looked around and have seen some similar questions, but i still couldn't get my program to work. I'm just practicing at home (I'm in high school) couldn't leave this question unsolved and move on. This is my code, but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
    String inputAge, outputOK, outputCancel;
    Integer Age;

    inputAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Age To Find Your Year Of Birth", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);


    if (inputAge == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

        System.out.println("You Were Born In The Year " + (2018 - (Age = Integer.parseInt(inputAge))));

    } else if (inputAge == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: *i still couldn't get my program to work*: What exactly went wrong? Please describe the actual and desired behavior.

Comment: Have you an exception ?

Comment: Their is a red line under the if statement and else if  statement. "if (inputAge == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){" and "else if (inputAge == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){" lines are the error. Everything else is fine

Comment: Also, what does an exception mean? I know what the word means in english, but how does it relate to the program?

Comment: Ok so i looked over the error in the run section and it says bad binary operand "==" and that the first type: java.lang.String and the second type: int. I get the part where the first one is a string, but how is JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION an integer?

Comment: `CANCEL_OPTION` is an integer and inputAge is a String you can not compare String to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that the first type: java.lang.String and the second type: int.

The `showInputDialog(...)` method returns a String, not an int. So you can't just assign the value to an int. You need to convert the String to an int. Something like:

```
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
int age = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have two errors:

If you write your code with an **IDE** not a **TextEditor** it detects that is impossible to compare `inputAge` to `OK_OPTION` because :

`inputAge` is **String** and `OK_OPTION` is an **static Integer**

The second error is `if (inputAge == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)` ,let say you convert the result of inputAge to Integer like this : `Integer.valueOf(inputAge)` and we get as result :

`if (Integer.ValueOf(inputAge) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)` but if you exlore in `JOptionPane class` you will find that `JOptionPane.OK_OPTION` is :`public static final int OK_OPTION = 0;` which means this part of code:

```
if (inputAge == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

        System.out.println("You Were Born In The Year " + (2018 - (Age = Integer.parseInt(inputAge))));

    }
```

Does not execute only if the user write **0** ,I don't know your point exactly but i think the logic is :

> We use JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parameters) for asking the user to
>   type a String after that we make our testing on this value.

In your code you made a test for final [static](https://www.guru99.com/java-static-variable-methods.html)  variables,so I guess your code will be like this :

```
inputAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Age To Find Your Year Of Birth", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (inputAge != null) {
        if (!inputAge.isEmpty()) {
            if (Integer.valueOf(inputAge) != 0) {

                System.out.println("You Were Born In The Year " + (2018 - (Age = Integer.parseInt(inputAge))));

            }
        }
    }
```

With this method your code can gets the input and calculate the result.

Comment: Thanks that really helped. also, what action can be done if Cancel_Option is selected. Ok works fine but cancel gives error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null. And how do u make it so the input box starts of empty with cursor